# Tutorials on Quantum Variational Algorithm

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, fourier-transform, education

I am interested in learning about quantum algorithms, especially quantum variational algorithms. I would like to know where I can find resources that delve into specific quantum variational algorithms and provide tutorials on how to run such algorithms using Qiskit, PennyLane, or any other free platform.

I have a basic theoretical knowledge of the quantum Fourier transform and Shor's algorithm, but I lack practical implementation knowledge.

---

***[Cross-posted on qc.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/32733/55)***